# Difficulty performing actions in a finite loop with user input

Tags: loops, common-lisp, user-input

I'm using Allegro CL Express on a Mac and I'm not sure if the program is having difficulties, or my code is poorly formed.  I'm trying to take 4 user input integers and then add them after the last value is entered

Desired outcome:

```
(stuff)

Enter a number: 4

Enter a number: 3

Enter a number: 2

Enter a number: 1

10
```

Here's what I currently have:

```
(defun stuff ()
  (loop repeat 4
        sum (format t "Enter a number: ")
            (parse-integer (read-line))))
```

EDIT:

After some great help, here is what I have:

```
CG-USER(18): (defun stuff ()
(loop repeat 4
    sum (progn 
          (format t "Enter a number: ")
          (parse-integer (read-line)))))
STUFF
CG-USER(19): (stuff)
Enter a number: 1
```

It just hangs after I enter an integer and press return.

Comment: Note that in portable Common Lisp you need to call `finish-output`, to make sure that buffered output is done. Here you need to call it after then call to `format`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a compiler helps.  Look what SBCL says when evaluating your form:

```
CL-USER> (defun stuff ()
           (loop repeat 4
              sum 
                (format t "Enter a number: ")
                (parse-integer (read-line))))
; in: DEFUN STUFF
;     (LOOP REPEAT 4
;           SUM (FORMAT T "Enter a number: ") (PARSE-INTEGER (READ-LINE)))
; 
; caught ERROR:
;   during macroexpansion of (LOOP REPEAT 4 ...). Use *BREAK-ON-SIGNALS* to
;   intercept.
;   
;    (PARSE-INTEGER
;     (READ-LINE)) found where a LOOP keyword or LOOP type keyword expected
;   current LOOP context: SUM (FORMAT T "Enter a number: ") (PARSE-INTEGER
;                                                            (READ-LINE)).
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   caught 1 ERROR condition
STUFF
```

The most important part there is

```
;    (PARSE-INTEGER
;     (READ-LINE)) found where a LOOP keyword or LOOP type keyword expected
;   current LOOP context: SUM (FORMAT T "Enter a number: ") (PARSE-INTEGER
;                                                            (READ-LINE)).
```

So it's getting **(PARSE-INTEGER (READ-LINE))** where a loop keyword or type is expected.  Why's that?  The documentation for [**loop**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_loop.htm) should tell us.  **sum** is a numeric accumulation:

```
numeric-accumulation::= { count | counting | sum |
                          summing | maximize | maximizing | 
                          minimize | minimizing }
                        {form | it} 
                        [into simple-var] [type-spec]
```

So, after **sum**, there should be a single **form**.  You'd just need to wrap your prompt and the call to **read-line** in, e.g., a **progn** to produce a single form:

```
(defun stuff ()
  (loop repeat 4
        sum (progn 
              (format *query-io* "Enter a number: ")
              (parse-integer (read-line *query-io*)))))
```

Note also that I used the stream [***query-io***](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_debug_.htm#STquery-ioST) for input and output. You don't *have* to do that, but it's probably a bit more robust, since:

> The value of ***query-io***, called query I/O, is a bidirectional stream
>   to be used when asking questions of the user. The question should be
>   output to this stream, and the answer read from it.

Comment: You are a wizard and I'm in your debt (as many are here I'm sure).  Thank you and sorry for the noobiness.

Comment: @Aaron It's a good habit to get into the habit of looking at the HyperSpec.  It's especially true in some of the more complicated bits of CL (e.g., LOOP), because it's easy for implementations to have subtle differences (or bugs) such that code that works in one place might not work in another.  That's why it was so easy to spot this particular bug;  I've run into things like it before and had to decipher the same kinds of messages. :) Happy Lisping!

Comment: I might have spoken a little soon, will post results above.  It's hanging in the program after the I enter the first integer for some unknown reason.  Is there anything I could provide that may give insight?

Comment: I interrupted the debugger and got this:                                Break: A new process was created to show this dialog and to set the process-quantum of very thread to a small value (0.1 seconds) to facilitate debugging a busy thread.
The quanta will return to their former values upon returning from this break.
Error: There's junk in this string:
       "1Break: A new process was created to show this dialog and to set the process-quantum of".
[condition type: PARSE-ERROR]

Comment: Honestly, I think it may be ACL -- GTK just broke as well.

Comment: Since you mention GTK, I assume you're running Allegro with some sort of X11 based interface?  Or are you running under SLIME?  this is part of the reason that I made a point about \*query-io*;  there can be lots of different streams floating around in big applications.  One streams \*standard-output/input\* isn't necessarily another's.

Comment: Yea, Allegro with X11.